# PuLP : What am I wrong in Objective Function?

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp, minimization

I created objective function and found the error in syntax of Excess below.

**Excess = (inv[m]+order[m]for m in material) - sum(produce[i]*usage[i][m]for m in material for i in product)**

The Excess cost = (Inventory + Quantity order) -  Total quantity used

Constraint
Material Quantity used
I would like to fix that quantity of material is used for production will not exceed total inventory what we have plus total quantity that we order more.

So Material Quantity used <= Total Inventory + Total order

Can anyone suggest for my missing ?

```
product = ['S1', 'S2']

material = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'I', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M']
inv_bf = 40000

product_cost = {'S1': 4.28, 'S2': 4.28,}

usage = {'S1': {'A': 12.24,
                'D': 12.24,
                'E': 0.014,
                'F': 0.095,
                'G': 12.24,
                'H': 0.589,
                'J': 24.24,
                'K': 0.005,
                'L': 0.0105},
         'S2': {'A': 12.24,
                'D': 12.24,
                'E': 0.014,
                'F': 0.095,
                'G': 12.24,
                'H': 0.589,
                'J': 24.24,
                'K': 0.005,
                'L': 0.0105}}

inv = {'A': 7645.8, 'B': 2470, 'C': 4526,
       'D': 6678, 'J': 4180.92, 'G': 6879,
       'E': 159.5, 'F': 717.4, 'I': 764.1,
       'H': 1302.69, 'K': 248.79, 'L': 235,
       'M': 179.4}

cost = {'A': 0.03, 'B': 0.03, 'C': 0.056,
        'D': 0.151, 'J': 0.024, 'G': 0.88,
        'E': 5.156, 'F': 13.04, 'I': 11.09,
        'H': 6.833, 'K': 11.261, 'L': 10.118,
        'M': 11.914}'''

# Define variables
# How many unit will produce ?
produce = LpVariable.dicts("produce", product, lowBound=0, cat='Integer')

# How many quantity of material to order more ?
order = LpVariable.dicts("order", material, lowBound=0, cat='Integer')

# Define and initialize model
model = LpProblem("total_cost", LpMinimize)

# Objective Function

Total_ProCost = lpSum(product_cost[i]*produce[i] for i in product)
Total_MatCost = lpSum(order[m]*cost[m] for m in material)
Excess = lpSum(inv[m]+order[m]for m in material) - \
         lpSum(produce[i]*usage[i][m]for m in material for i in product if m in usage[i].keys())

objective = Total_ProCost + Total_MatCost + lpSum(Excess*cost[m]for m in material)
model.setObjective(objective)

# Define Constraints

# Material Quantity used
for i in product:
    model += lpSum(produce[i]*usage[i][m]for m in material for i in product if m in usage[i].keys()) <= lpSum(inv[m] +\
              order[m] for m in material)
```

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Comment: I got the message as below. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\sim.py", line 81, in <module>
    ExcessCost = (inv[m]+order[m]for m in material) - sum(produce[i]*usage[i][m]for m in material for i in product)

Comment: Where's the rest of the traceback? Remember that you can (and should) edit your post to add it, rather than post it in a comment.

Comment: @jjramsey  I add more detail and question in the post. Could you please advise  ?

Comment: Add *all* of the traceback to your post, not just the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you are creating the expression for `Excess cost` you have a parenthetical **without** `sum` or more likely `lpSum` in front of it.  So it is then a python generator without an expression in front of it, so that is causing your problem.

Also, in your follow-on expression, you are multiplying `Excess cost` * `cost[]` which seems very odd.  Either you have the math wrong or the variable names are goofy because cost squared is probably nonsensical.

#### EDIT:

Try this.  I think this is what you want.  You need `lpSum` in front of your summations in order to construct the math model.  And in your `Excess` statement you were not checking if `usage` had the material in it, so that was generating key errors as you were summing over all materials, even though some are not in `usage`.  I put a conditional into the correct summation...

```
# Objective Function

Total_ProCost = lpSum(product_cost[i]*produce[i] for i in product)
Total_MatCost = lpSum(order[m]*cost[m] for m in material)
Excess = lpSum(inv[m]+order[m]for m in material) - \
         lpSum(produce[i]*usage[i][m]for m in material for i in product if m in usage[i].keys())

objective = Total_ProCost + Total_MatCost + lpSum(Excess*cost[m]for m in material)

model.setObjective(objective)
```

Comment: You are right. the one reason is because of wrong variable name.
I tried to use lpSum as your suggestion below but we still found some error about LpAffineExpression.         
Could you please suggest more ?
           
`# Objective Function

Total_ProCost = lpSum(product_cost[i]*produce[i] for i in product)
Total_MatCost = lpSum(order[m]*cost[m] for m in material)
Excess = lpSum(inv[m]+order[m]for m in material) - lpSum(produce[i]*usage[i][m]for m in material for i in product)

objective = Total_ProCost + Total_MatCost + lpSum(Excess*cost[m]for m in material)`

Comment: I tried as your suggestion in Objective Function already. but I still have question when I define constraint what is related to Excess. Should I put the if m in usage[i].keys()  in the constraint ? I edit and add more constraints in question above. Could you please suggest ?

Comment: You could do it several ways...depending on what you want to do and what "the math" is.  You could create a separate subset, use a conditional (as I did) or a variety of other things.  You just need to ensure that the keys you use for params/variables are valid...or suffer the errors.